# How do I handle suspension of Windows 10 apps correctly in Visual C# or C++?

Tags: c#, c++, windows-10, suspend, uwp

The MSDN-Site has only old information applicable for Windows 8/8.l Metro/Pseudo UWP apps. In this apps Microsoft provide a complicated suspension helper class which is not available in Windows 10 UWP Blank app templates. So how do I handle suspension in Windows 10 UWP apps. I haven't found any information on how to handle suspension in this apps.

Does anybody know how do I have to handle suspension?

Comment: what do you mean by `handle`? Do you want your app to be notified on suspend/wakeup or your app to initiate a suspend/wakeup?

Comment: No I want to save the app state (filled forms, text, current page etc.). As far as I know, I have to save this to restore this state after the user switch back to the app, because sometimes the system free the app out of the memory to provide more memory to other applications or uwp apps.

Comment: If you directly copy the suspension class from win8.1 project to win10 project, will it be ok?

Comment: Maybe, didn't tried that yet, because there is many other stuff in the MainPage.cs file added by visual studio in a Win 8.1. I will give it a try.

Comment: Gave it a try, but it doesn't work as expected (the back button shows up; even on the main page). Try Template10 as suggested by  @StuartSmith

Answer (score 0):

The example your are looking for does not exist in the default templates given out with visual studio. There is a project to create template that does have this functionality. You can find these templates at...

https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10

Here is the code from template 10 on suspending and resuming

```
 Resuming += (s, e) => { OnResuming(s, e); };
            Suspending += async (s, e) =>
            {
                // one, global deferral
                var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
                try
                {
                    foreach (var service in WindowWrapper.ActiveWrappers.SelectMany(x => x.NavigationServices))
                    {
                        // date the cache (which marks the date/time it was suspended)
                        service.FrameFacade.SetFrameState(CacheDateKey, DateTime.Now.ToString());
                        // call view model suspend (OnNavigatedfrom)
                        await service.SuspendingAsync();
                    }
                    // call system-level suspend
                    await OnSuspendingAsync(s, e);
                }
                catch { }
                finally { deferral.Complete(); }
            };
```